# Error in Apple script for saving password-protected PDF

Tags: pdf, applescript, pdf-generation, password-protection

Can anyone please help me find a solution for the error I'm getting? MacOS is Monterrey and this script used to work in Big Sur.

It seems it is unable to find splitter group 3 (which would the page style). And the same happens when it tries to find "PDF" splitter and save as PDF.

I would appreciate any help/suggestions you can provide.

```
-- Don't change this

set FixedPassword to "somePW"

--Change the following for each Review accordingly

set exam to "2"
set session to "5"
set VarPassword to "barcelona"

set outpath to "/Users/user/Dropbox/Physics" & " - " & "Current/2023-1-Spring/UF/2." & " " & "Chapter" & " " & "Reviews/" & ¬
    "Exam" & " " & exam & " " & "Session" & " " & session & "/E" & exam & "S" & session & ".pdf"

set SaveFolder to "/Users/user/Dropbox/Physics" & " - " & "Current/2023-1-Spring/UF/2." & " " & "Chapter" & " " & "Reviews/" & ¬
    "Exam" & " " & exam & " " & "Session" & " " & session

set FileName to "E" & exam & "S" & session & " " & "(Password" & " - " & VarPassword & ").pdf"


--Saving PDF with password protection
tell application "Preview"
    activate
    open outpath
end tell


activate application "Preview"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Preview"
        keystroke "p" using command down
        delay 0.5
        tell front window
            repeat until exists sheet 1
                delay 1
            end repeat
            tell sheet 1
                tell splitter group 3
                    click pop up button 3
                    click menu item "Review 216 by 279 mm" of menu 1 of pop up button 3
                end tell
                tell splitter group 3
                    click menu button "PDF"
                    repeat until exists menu 1 of menu button "PDF"
                        delay 3
                    end repeat
                    click menu item "Save as PDF" of menu 1 of menu button "PDF"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
        
        -- Make sure the save dialog is visible
        repeat until exists sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            delay 5
        end repeat
        
        tell sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            click button "Security Options..."
        end tell
        
        tell window "PDF Security Options"
            set selected to true
            set focused to true
            (* click the checkbox to on *)
            -- NOTE: for some reason there is a delay of about 6 seconds here, I do not know why
            tell checkbox "Require password to open document"
                click
            end tell
            (* add the password and confirm *)
            keystroke VarPassword
            keystroke (ASCII character 9)
            keystroke VarPassword
            
            tell its checkbox "Require password to copy text, images and other content"
                click
            end tell
            (* add the password and confirm *)
            keystroke FixedPassword
            keystroke (ASCII character 9)
            keystroke FixedPassword
            
            click button "OK"
        end tell
        
        repeat until exists sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        
        -- Press command+shift+g to show the "Go" drop down sheet
        keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
        repeat until exists sheet of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        
        delay 0.5
        keystroke SaveFolder
        delay 0.5
        
        click button "Go" of sheet of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
        
        -- Now that we are in our desired folder, set the file name and save
        set value of text field 1 of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window to FileName
        
        click button "Save" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
        
    end tell
end tell
```

But it gives the following error:
[image]

Comment: I don't think that there is a splitter group 3… hence the error. Remove that 'tell' statement and try again (i.e. the click command should be directly inside the 'tell sheet 1' block.

Comment: To confirm the correct chain of elements, create a new script with only this line: `tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Preview" to tell window 1 to tell sheet 1 to UI elements`. Then open the print dialogue as it is in your screen shot and run the script. Once the results appear, search within them for `pop up button 3` and you should find the correct way to reference the pop up. I should note that companies change their dialogues from time to time so perhaps that is what happened here.

Comment: To solve this issue, you can try to update the script to find the correct elements in the Preview interface. One way to do this is to record a new script using the AppleScript Editor while performing the steps manually in the Preview application. This will give you the updated script with the correct element paths.

Another possible solution is to use a different PDF editor application that has a more stable and consistent API, such as Adobe Acrobat or PDFpen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I don't get that error anymore, but I managed to fix some other errors and make it work by increasing the delay and adding a keystroke to return (in previous OS versions it wasn't needed)

```
tell application "Preview"
    activate
    open outpath
end tell
activate application "Preview"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Preview"
        keystroke "p" using command down
        delay 0.5
        tell front window
            repeat until exists sheet 1
                delay 1
            end repeat
            tell sheet 1
                tell splitter group 1
                    click pop up button 3
                    --click menu item "Review" of menu 1 of pop up button 3
                    click menu item "Review 216 by 279 mm" of menu 1 of pop up button 3
                end tell
                tell splitter group 1
                    click menu button "PDF"
                    repeat until exists menu 1 of menu button "PDF"
                        delay 0.02
                    end repeat
                    click menu item "Save as PDF" of menu 1 of menu button "PDF"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
        
        -- Make sure the save dialog is visible
        repeat until exists sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            delay 5
        end repeat
        
        --return name of every button of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
        
        tell sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            click button "Security Options…"
        end tell
        
        tell window "PDF Security Options"
            set selected to true
            set focused to true
            (* click the checkbox to on *)
            -- NOTE: for some reason there is a delay of about 6 seconds here, I do not know why
            tell checkbox "Require password to open document"
                click
            end tell
            (* add the password and confirm *)
            keystroke VarPassword
            keystroke (ASCII character 9)
            keystroke VarPassword
            
            tell its checkbox "Require password to copy text, images and other content"
                click
            end tell
            (* add the password and confirm *)
            keystroke FixedPassword
            keystroke (ASCII character 9)
            keystroke FixedPassword
            
            click button "OK"
        end tell
        
        repeat until exists sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        
        -- Press command+shift+g to show the "Go" drop down sheet
        keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
        repeat until exists sheet of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        
        delay 0.5
        keystroke SaveFolder
        delay 0.5
        
        --click button "Go" of sheet of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
        keystroke return
        
        -- Now that we are in our desired folder, set the file name and save
        set value of text field 1 of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window to FileName
        
        click button "Save" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of front window
        
    end tell
end tell
```